# Wordpress antivirus plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Does someone here know how to install antimalware plugins on wordpress. My website is hosted by bluehost and does contain malware

Glad if someone here know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) is a popular security plugin for WordPress, you can try it and scan your website.

There are other plugin as well you can search for *WordPress security plugin*